# Regex.Matches is skipping over a match? c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to identify substrings found in a string such as:

> "CityABCProcess Test" or "cityABCProcess Test"

to yield :

> [ "City/city", "ABC", "Process", "Test" ]

1. The first string in the substring can be lowercase or uppercase
2. Any substring with recurring uppercase letters will be a substring until a lowercase letter or space is found "ABCProcess -> ABC, ABC Process -> ABC"
3. If there is an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter the substring will be  everything until the next uppercase letter.

The regular expression we have been using is:

> "[A-Z][a-z]+|([A-Z]|[0-9])+\b|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|([a-z]|[0-9])+"

This has been working great but breaks in the case of a string:

> "X-999"

We are implementing it in this fashion:

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("[A-Z][a-z]+|([A-Z]|[0-9])+\b|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|([a-z]|[0-9])+");

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(name, builder.ToString()))
        {
            //do things with each match
        }
```

The problem here is it is not matching on the 'X' but only the '999'. Any ideas? I tested it with regexr.com and it says this regex should match on both substrings.

Comment: Maybe it is because there is no `-` anywhere in regex, try with `[A-Z][a-z]+|([A-Z]|[-0-9])+\b|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|([a-z]|[0-9])+`

Answer (score 4):

`\b` is being interpreted as an escape sequence (\u0008, backspace) in the C# string.

Escape the slash (i.e., `\\b`), or use a verbatim string using the `@` symbol:

```
        builder.Append(@"[A-Z][a-z]+|([A-Z]|[0-9])+\b|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|([a-z]|[0-9])+");
```